# IN Clause in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I had one SQL Query:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM CATEGORY_LANGUAGE 
WHERE 
CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)
AND LANGUAGE_ID=1
```

**IN THIS QUERY:**

11 -> aa

22 -> bb

**I want records to be returned like this:**

aa

bb

**While running the query returns:**

bb

aa

Kindly, let me know to further elaborate my question.

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  Is it just coming back in the wrong order?  If so, couldn't you just put an ORDER BY to fix it?

Comment: I assume you want the result to be ordered in the same way as the "IN tuple" in your SQL, not necessarily alphabetical?

Comment: @Doc Brown: "tuple"?! `CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)` is merely syntactic sugar for `(CATEGORY_ID = 11 OR CATEGORY_ID = 22)`. Have you heard of the Associative Law for Logical OR? The SQL engine is certainly free to evaluate these in any order it sees fit. And what kind of tuple is ordered? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is something new:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM CATEGORY_LANGUAGE 
WHERE 
    CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)
    AND LANGUAGE_ID=1
ORDER BY
    field(CATEGORY_ID, 11, 22)
```

This is catered to mysql.  Just make sure the ids are in the same order in the `field()` function as they are in the `in()` function.

Comment: @Doc we posted at the same time :p so yes, after

Comment: So, whoever voted this up, you are aware that may not be the solution the OP is after?

Comment: @Doc, thats why I said 'From your example' if OP clarifies I will correct it, if it actually is what OP needs he will be happy and everything will be merry

Comment: @Sydenam: I am aware of that, otherwise I would have downvoted your answer ;-) From the question title I think one may assume the IN tuple is what the OP is after.

Comment: @Doc Unfortunately he doesn't seem to be participating in this discussion :p

Comment: The result is not coming up as written in IN clause. Adding the "Order by Name" doesn't correct the result.

Comment: @ankitjava What SQL system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to sort by category_id:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM CATEGORY_LANGUAGE 
WHERE 
CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)
AND LANGUAGE_ID=1
ORDER BY CATEGORY_ID
```

If, on the other hand, you always want to have the same order as in your IN-Clause, I'd use some kind of INSTR() magic (depends on your RDBMS, this works for Oracle; I put the hyphens in for readability and to avoid possible errors if one category_id is a prefix of another):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM CATEGORY_LANGUAGE 
WHERE 
CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)
AND LANGUAGE_ID=1
ORDER BY INSTR('11-22', TO_CHAR(CATEGORY_ID));
```

Explanation: TO_CHAR() converts CATEGORY_ID to a string, and INSTR() returns the index where the second string was found in the first - here, we use it to extract the sort order for our category_id from '11-22'.

Comment: Query suggested by you works on some id and not working on some id.

Comment: @ankitjava Do you have an example where it does not work as expected?

Comment: For id's = "1303393383, 1303293381" result is returned correctly.        But when Id changed to "1301462530, 1301642485" result order has changed. Kindly let me know to further elaborate.

Comment: @ankitjava you're right, there was an error (I had the order of arguments for INSTR() reversed). Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code

```
CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22)
```

is merely syntactic sugar for

```
(CATEGORY_ID = 11 OR CATEGORY_ID = 22)
```

The SQL engien is free to evaluate these predicates in any order is sees fit (hint: `OR` is associative).

It may look like a set, relation, table, tuple, list, bag etc but isn't.

SQL only really has one data structure: the table. Therefore, put your values into rows of a staging table (could be a CTE). A table doesn't have any intrinsic ordering so if this is a requirement you will need to give your stating a sort order attribute. You can then `JOIN` the staging table to your target base table.

Here's some Standard SQL as an example:

```
WITH STAGING (CATEGORY_ID, SORT_ORDER)
     AS
     (
      SELECT CATEGORY_ID, SORT_ORDER
        FROM (
              VALUES (11, 0), 
                     (22, 1)
             ) AS STAGING (CATEGORY_ID, SORT_ORDER)
     )
SELECT C1.NAME, S1.SORT_ORDER
  FROM CATEGORY_LANGUAGE AS C1
       INNER JOIN STAGING AS S1
          ON C1.CATEGORY_ID = S1.CATEGORY_ID 
 WHERE LANGUAGE_ID = 1
 ORDER 
    BY SORT_ORDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  NAME 
FROM 
  CATEGORY_LANGUAGE  
WHERE  
  CATEGORY_ID IN (11, 22) 
AND 
  LANGUAGE_ID=1 
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Maybe it is just an order problem

Comment: Well, I don't believe that will work (there is no column CATEGORY_LANGUAGE)

Comment: THank you @Doc. i missed that

Comment: and you missed my comment to the OPs question too, I assume? By the way, DESC will order the output in descending order (bb before aa).

Comment: You are right, DESC will be switch to ASC for the correct order